# Can't play this video error when playing video from URI

Tags: android, video, video-processing

In My application, I want to show video from server URI path,
Here, for the first time video is playing and when I want to play the video for the second time the video is not playing and showing a popup like Can't play this video

Below is my error

```
 E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri=https://www.merastories.com/VideoFiles/a81d1e5c-3e23-418a-9ba8-fca601d1a966-VID_20180322_152225.mp4
          java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.merastories.com/VideoFiles/a81d1e5c-3e23-418a-9ba8-fca601d1a966-VID_20180322_152225.mp4
              at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1123)
              at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
              at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:881)
              at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1018)
              at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:437)
              at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:742)
              at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:676)
              at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:203)
              at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6708)
              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:822)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code too

Comment: please post the line of code which you set the URL to

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse(Weburlinfo.Mera_BaseUrl+videopathinfo);
        Log.i("uri info",""+uri);
        videopath.setVideoURI(uri);
        videopath.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        videopath.start();

        videopath.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //close the progress dialog when buffering is done
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });

Comment: @kishore, Please add that part in question, not in comment.

Comment: this `url` is not playing also in Browsers

Comment: above url is working in internet explorer but in chrome only audio is working when download then it working in local player

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String path="https://www.merastories.com/VideoFiles/a81d1e5c-3e23-418a-9ba8-fca601d1a966-VID_20180322_152225.mp4";
Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);
VideoView videoview=findViewById(R.id.videoview);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Comment: try some other sample urls

Comment: Other url is working fine when come to above url, it works for first time and showing error for send time

Answer (score 0):

Use ExoPlayer for showing the video from anyplace 
   " compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2' "

CODE for Using Exoplayer

```
 if (videoUri != null) {
        shouldAutoPlay = true;
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, MyApplication.getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)), (TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeter);
        window = new Timeline.Window();

        initializePlayer(videoUrl);
    }


  private void initializePlayer(Uri iVideoUri) {

    simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
    DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(iVideoUri,
            mediaDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

    player.prepare(mediaSource);

}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        shouldAutoPlay = player.getPlayWhenReady();
        player.release();
        player = null;
        trackSelector = null;
    }
```